# Xamarin Ios build hangs on signing

Tags: ios, xamarin, teamcity

We build ios using xamarin, the build hangs on signing and didn't throw any exception about 2.5 hours

Sign and provision profile is good. What could be?

[image]

```
        Target _CodesignAppBundle:
            Codesign Task
              CodesignAllocate: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoo              Entitlements: obj/iPhone/Release/Entitlements.xcent
              Resource: bin/iPhone/Release/App.app
              ResourceRules: <null>
              SigningKey: ECFF24B11990B9BXXXXXXX194A29B83E87776A7B
              ExtraArgs: <null>
            Tool /usr/bin/codesign execution started with arguments: -v --force --sign ECFF24B11990B9BXXXXXXX194A29B83E87776A7B --entitlements /Users/admin/buildAgent_2/temp/buildTmp/SOURCE/App/obj/iPhone/Release/Entitlements.xcent /Users/admin/buildAgent_2/temp/buildTmp/SOURCE/App/bin/iPhone/Release/App.app
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it requires to unlock the keychain access : a popup waiting for the keychain password is prompted on your server, but you don't see it.

I had to deal with this kind of problem when configuring a Xamarin app on Jenkins CI.
If so, just unlock the keychain with a bash script :

```
KEYCHAIN=/Users/xxx/Keychains/xxx.keychain
security -v unlock-keychain -p mypassword $KEYCHAIN
```

Comment: We use teamcity and have this step: security -v unlock-keychain -p qweqwe %env.HOME%/Library/Keychains/login.keychain